# Are there any javascript AMD frameworks that use deferreds?

Tags: javascript, amd, deferred

It seems like deferreds are the very useful to keep code inline, are there any amd frameworks that use them primarily?
For instance:

```
require(['a','b','c'], function(a,b,c){

});
```

can be

```
var dfda = requiredfd('a');
var dfdb = requiredfd('b');
var dfdc = requiredfd('c');
whenall(dfda,dfdb,dfdc,function(a,b,c){

})
```

or some-such which seems to be wordy but allows you to pass references that are not used.

Also what other benefits does it present.

Comment: How would you load in Deferred functionality and the implementation of `whenall`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with a AMD framework that uses promises.
However, you could write your own `requiredfd`-function to get the desired behavior.

**Example:**

```
// Use RequireJS and jQuery.Deferred.
var requiredfd = function(dependencies) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    require(dependencies, function() {
        dfd.resolveWith(null, arguments);
    });

    return dfd.promise();
};

var promise = requiredfd(['underscore', 'jQuery']);
promise.done(function(_, $) {
    console.log('requiredfd');
    console.log('underscore:', _);
    console.log('jQuery:', $);
});
```

One benefit it present, is that you could pass the promise to other functions in your application.

Working example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fz3Ut/)